# Error [37] : Unable to calculate. Metadata error - SCP plugin in QGIS - Preprocessing landsat 8

Tags: qgis, scp

I am trying to preprocess Landsat 8 data using the SCP plugin - all the bands are processed except for bands 1 and 9. The metadata is read correctly in the table but on clicking "Run" I hit upon the error.

> Error [37] : Unable to calculate. Metadata error - SCP plugin in QGIS
> Preprocessing Landsat 8

I'm using QGIS 3.16.2.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

I had posted the question on SCP forum on Facebook and had a response from the author. The plugin does not preprocess Landsat bands 1, 8 and 9.